# Shrink Array maintaining number distribution in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a function that builds an array with N elements, with the distribution to 0 to 100 . For example:

```
int[] a = {100,80, 50,20, 0};
```

I want to resize this array to fill a new array with the size of N = 10, but keep the number distribution of the previous array. I think that with some probabilistic distribution, I can achieve this, but don't know how to do it.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the number distribution of the previous array"?

Comment: That sounds like a task that's more at home at math.stackexchange.com than here. And it also needs more specification: Which properties do you want to keep consistent? Max/Min/Average/Sum/Distribution/? You can't have all of them (count for example will be ... hard).

Comment: Humm, lets say that we have the array [1,30,70,100]. How do we make this array of percentages to a new array with 10 elements?

Comment: @JoachimSauer, i understand that. In my case, i want to keep the distribution.

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais: can you explain what "the distribution" is?

Comment: @JoachimSauer lets say i have a X axis in a graph from 0 to 70. I have to transform this axis to 0 to 10, maintaining the same distribuiton of values in the graph.

Comment: I think without *knowing* the distribution, taking a (truly) random sample of your set is about as close as you'll get to that.

Comment: Instead of repeating the word “distribution” again, please describe exactly what numeric values we would see if `{100, 80, 50, 20, 0}` were transformed into a ten-element array with the “same distribution.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question right, the goal is to redistribute numbers from `source` array into new array, putting numbers in bins by 10. So, if number is `0` it should go to new array at index `0` (since it's in the range `[0, 10]`), and if the number is `20` - it should go to index `1` (since, it's in the range `[11, 20]`), and so forth.

If the assumption is correct, then this is one approach:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReDistribution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] distribution = {100, 80, 50, 20, 0};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reDistribute(distribution)));
    // prints: [0, 20, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 80, 0, 100]
  }

 /**
  * Assuming source array contains only integers in range [0, 100], redistributes into array
  * index       0,        1,        2,        3,        4,        5,        6,       7,         8,        9
  * range [0, 10], [11, 20], [21, 30], [31, 40], [41, 50], [51, 60], [61, 70], [71, 80], [81, 90], [91, 100]
  */
  private static int[] reDistribute(int[] source) {
    int[] target = new int[10];
    for (int num : source) {
      target[(num - 1) / 10] = num;
    }
    return target;
  }
}
```